# Database of scientific paper abstracts

Tags: doi

I am trying to find a database with scientific papers which will allow me to:
1. Get metadata of papers by doi (including abstracts);
2. Do this stuff regularly (e.g. daily updated);
3. Ability to download whole existing database.
I know about Crossref API, however, only 3% of all publications presented have abstract (and none of biggest publishers like Springer or Elsevier provide them). On the other side I see some projects like [Dimensions](https://www.dimensions.ai) or [Researcher](https://www.researcher-app.com) which already implemented mentioned functionality. So the question is: does somebody know such services (possibly not free) and had experience working with them?

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at Semantic Scholar (https://www.semanticscholar.org/)? They have an API that supports the first of your requirements (http://api.semanticscholar.org/) and also provide the "Open Research Corpus" (http://labs.semanticscholar.org/corpus/) which should satisfy your third requirement. It is a smaller database than what is provided by Scopus or Web of Science, but both of those require subscriptions to fully use their APIs and don't (as far as I know) have a real way for you to purchase a full download of the database.